# Sorting based on number of conditions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting

I want to filter out data from a table using multiple conditions, so I'm using the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM `usersposts`
WHERE (LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%')
OR LOWER(`fname`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')
OR  LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')) AND approval=1"
```

Which works as expected, but now I need to sort the result based on the number of conditions satisfy by the row. For example, if one row satisfies all the or statements then it should be on the top and single condition satisfying should be at the end. How can I achieve this?

What I'd tried :

```
WHERE (LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%')
OR LOWER(`fname`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')
OR  LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')) AND approval=1
ORDER BY
    WHEN LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%') AND LOWER(`fname`) = LOWER('{$location}') AND  LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}') THEN 1
    WHEN (LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%') AND LOWER(`fname`) = LOWER('{$keywords}'))
     OR (LOWER(`post_author_fname`) = LOWER('{$keywords}') AND  LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}'))
     OR (LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%') AND  LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')) THEN 2
    ELSE 3 END 
ASC;
```

Is there any simple alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each condition evaluates to true/false, which is equivalent to 1/0 in MySQL. You use the sum of conditions to sort by the number of conditions matched.

```
ORDER BY (LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%')) +
         (LOWER(`fname`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')) +
         (LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')) DESC
```

Comment: This looks simple :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can sum your conditions as another column and order by that column 
because like and = will return 0 and 1

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM `usersposts`
WHERE
    (LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%')
OR
    LOWER(`fname`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')
OR
    LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')) 
AND
    approval=1
ORDER BY (
    IF( (LOWER(`content`) LIKE LOWER('%{$keywords}%') ,1,0)
    + IF( LOWER(`fname`) = LOWER('{$keywords}') ,1,0)
    + IF( LOWER(`title`) = LOWER('{$keywords}')) ,1,0)
    ) DESC
;
```